# Is there a way to suppress interactive mode in zsh?

Tags: zsh

In zsh, is there a way to turn off interactive mode (specifically aliases) within a script that has been sourced interactively?

For example, if I define in `foo.zsh`:

```
#!/bin/zsh

a ha
```

and then do

```
alias a=echo
./foo.zsh
```

I get an error, because the alias is not applied; but if I do

```
. ./foo.zsh
```

I get `ha`.

Is there a way, within `foo.zsh`, to disable the alias `a`, even if it has been sourced with `.` ?

Comment: A shell running a script is always a non-interactive shell. All the same, the script can still access its tty. It is even possible to emulate an interactive shell in a script - [source](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/intandnonint.html). From [this answer](http://superuser.com/questions/46139/what-does-source-do), you're trying to run the script *in the current shell*, while at the same time *not wanting the script in the current shell*. Is using `source` absolutely necessary? What are you trying to do (is this a learning exersise, or a task requires `source`)?

Comment: @simont I'm using [Sebastian Celis's git prompt](http://sebastiancelis.com/2009/11/16/zsh-prompt-git-users/), and every once in awhile I break it by defining a new alias in my .zshrc.

Answer (score 1):

This is documented pretty clearly in the manual:

```
INTERACTIVE (-i, ksh: -i)
     This is an interactive shell.  This option is set upon
     initialisation if the standard input is a tty and commands are
     being read from standard input.  (See the discussion of
     SHIN_STDIN.)  This heuristic may be overridden by specifying a
     state for this option on the command line.  The value of this
     option can only be changed via flags supplied at invocation of the
     shell.  It cannot be changed once zsh is running.
```

but you don't need to turn off interactive mode just to prevent alias
expansion:

```
$ setopt no_aliases
$ . ./foo.zsh
./foo.zsh:3: command not found: a
$ setopt aliases   
$ . ./foo.zsh   
ha
```